# How to coerce num type between double and int

Tags: dart

Looking for a cleaner/better way to coerce "num" type based on generic result "T".
Example:

```
int iCartesianAngleInDegrees=45, _iDistanceBetween=85;
Vector<int> ivectXY=new Vector<int>(10,30);
ivectXY.moveByDegreesAndDistance(iCartesianAngleInDegrees, _iDistanceBetween);
```

In the moveByDegreesAndDistance method, my kludge checks runtimeType to invoke toInt or toDouble. It just does not seem proper to me. Any suggestions/hints appreciated?

```
class Vector<T extends num> extends Coordinate<T> {
...
/**
 * Advance x/y in Direction(Cartesian Degrees) for a given Distance
 * TODO:PerfTest
 **/
Vector<T> moveByDegreesAndDistance(T iDegrees, T iDistance) {
    //cartesianToCompass(135) = 225
    double _dblAngleInRadians = degreesToRadians(iDegrees),
            _dblX = iDistance * math.cos(_dblAngleInRadians),
            _dblY = iDistance * math.sin(_dblAngleInRadians);

    //This will not automatically coerce type
    //      x += _dblX as T;
    //      y += _dblY as T;

    if (_dblX is T) {
        x += _dblX;
        y += _dblY;
    } else {
        if (x.runtimeType == int) {
            x += _dblX.toInt();
            y += _dblY.toInt();
        } else {
            x += _dblX.toDouble();
            y += _dblY.toDouble();
        }
    }
    return this;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`_dblAngleInRadians`, `_dblX`, `_dblY` being `double` you only have to test if `iDegrees` is an `int` and use [toInt()](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/dev/#dart-core.num@id_toInt) in this case.

```dart
class Vector<T extends num> extends Coordinate<T> {
...
/**
 * Advance x/y in Direction(Cartesian Degrees) for a given Distance
 * TODO:PerfTest
 **/
Vector<T> moveByDegreesAndDistance(T iDegrees, T iDistance) {
    //cartesianToCompass(135) = 225
    double _dblAngleInRadians = degreesToRadians(iDegrees),
            _dblX = iDistance * math.cos(_dblAngleInRadians),
            _dblY = iDistance * math.sin(_dblAngleInRadians);

    //This will not automatically coerce type
    //      x += _dblX as T;
    //      y += _dblY as T;
    final isInt = iDegrees is int;
    x += isInt ? _dblX.toInt() : _dblX;
    y += isInt ? _dblY.toInt() : _dblY;
    return this;
}
```